# maximo - Enable/Disable section for security group

Tags: security, maximo

I'm using Maximo 7.5

I try to enable/disable section for specific security group. So i created this expression :

```
1 = (select 1 from GROUPUSER where USERID = :&PERSONID& and groupname in ( 'GR_1', 'GR_2'))
```

My expression is associated with a sigoption and my sigoption is associated to the section.
My sigoption has the rigth on my application.

```
When true --> inputmode = default
When false --> inputmode = readonly
```

But it doesn't work.

Is it right to use that SQL expression to do this? Or should I create a specific class to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish the same goal in Maximo.

I know you can disable modules, tabs and or fields, but I am not sure about sections.

This post discusses some of the different ways to restrict what is visible in Maximo by using the Conditional UI:

http://maximodev.blogspot.com/p/conditional-expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

One reason this might not work: never use the "default" input mode! If you want the default behaviour in Maximo, simply leave the inputmode empty - the "default" input mode works in some unexpected ways (doesn't let you save the record).

You could actually just create an "always true" condition and assign it to the specific security group. Set the section to readonly, but set the "true" condition of the security group to empty.

Answer (score 0):

-The first, make sure your expression is correct, then create Signature Option (note the **description** of Signature), then put the SigOption into the section you want to disable (readonly), go Configure Confitional Properties, select security group maxeveryone, select the condition above, condition (true/false depend on your purpose of condition), example: `:status in ('WAPPR')` if false properties is "inputmode" and value is "readonly", the true way is auto available to edit(you don't need to specify)

-Next step, find the users you want to set readonly option, determine which group they belong to. With each group (example: maxeveryone), find Application (example: work order tracking), find the **description** of the SignatureOptine you have created above, check to grant access for it.

-Logout the user you have granted access and Login again to apply the new access